# Export queries results from SAS to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, sas

I'm importing an `input.txt` into SAS.

The content of the file is:

```sas
SUBJECT GENDER HEIGHT WEIGHT
1 M 68.5 -155 
2 F 61.2 99 
3 F 63.0 115 
4 M 70.0 -205 
5 M 68.6 170 
6 F 65.1 -125 
7 M 72.4 220 
8 F 72.4 220
```

I want to export to Excel the following results, based on the WEIGHT column (if they are negative or not):

```
TOTAL NEGATIVE  % NEGATIVE
  8      -3         37,5%
```

I imagined the easiest way to do this is by creating 3 SELECT COUNT (*) queries and putting the results of each one into one variable, and then printing these variables into Excel, but i don't know how to do this exactly.

Also, there might be an easiest way.

By the way, I'm new to SAS, I've been working with it since a couple of days.

Any insights?

Comment: The first SAS e-learning course is free on the SAS website.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to SQL, no need for 3 separate queries.  You should be able to do all this in a single query with `CASE`:

```
select count(*), 
       count(case when weight < 0 then 1 end) negativecount, 
       count(case when weight < 0 then 1 end)/count(*) negativepercentage
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cc7d/1)

Should be easy enough to format the percentage as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC SQL;
create table WANT as
select count(*) as total,
sum(weight<0) as negative,
calculated negative/calculated total as percent format=percent8.2
from have;
quit;
```

The export portion depends on your environment. You can generate the code by going to File>Export and select Excel as the destination.